# Kotlin putExtra none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Complete Newbie to Kotlin, trying to get three values to pass across from textboxes to another page , im getting no errors put the info is not either being passed across or displayed i have tried for hours to get this to work with no avail.

Could someone point me in a good or right direction please.

I have now edited my code as given in the help below on the page that is now receiving the info i cannot get it to display.

```
PAGE1

package com.example.james.visitorapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val editText2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText2)
        val editText3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText3)
        val message1 = editText.text.toString()
        val message2 = editText2.text.toString()
        val message3 = editText3.text.toString()


        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, arrayOf(message1, message2, message3))
        }

        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

receiving page

package com.example.james.visitorapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.widget.TextView

class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        val message1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)
        val message2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)
        val message3 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)
        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
            text = message1

        }
        val textView2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
            text = message2

        }
        val textView3 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView3).apply {
            text = message3

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one

```
val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_1, message1)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_2, message2)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_3, message3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`putExtra()` does not have any overloads that expect `vararg`.

You could either send the messages in an `Array`:

```
putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGES, arrayOf(message1, message2, message3))
```

And obtain them with `getStringArrayExtra()` in the receiving `Activity`, for example:

```
// the inferred type of messages will be Array<String>
val messages = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGES)
// joining the messages into a single String and setting it as the text for the TextView
textView.text = messages.joinToString(separator = " ")
```

Or put them separately with different keys:

```
putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_1, message1)
putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_2, message2)
putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_3, message3)
```

(and obtain then one by one with `getStringExtra()`)

On a side note, calling `apply()` is redundant here (in both cases), you could just call `putExtra()` on the `Intent` instance directly:

```
val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java)
    .putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_1, message1)
    .putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_2, message2)
    .putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_3, message3)
```

Comment: Yes i managed to get it to work  :)  used the arrayof and obtained them with the get string extra thanks for the help i really appreciate it